# Metaphone search + wilcard search: no results for some query strings

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I've been trying to implement a search query suggestion feature that can also detect
misspelled words (using the metaphone morphology). I've been able to do this to a certain
extent, the problem is that there are certain query strings that are returning empty
results when they shouldn't be. See this example for instance:

The search list that was indexed:

`[   "clone samsung galaxy s5",
    "samsung galaxy ace 4gb",
    "samsung galaxy core i8262 battery",
    "samsung galaxy grand duos premium copy",
    "samsung galaxy grand prime g530",
    "samsung galaxy k3",
    "samsung galaxy note 3 red",
    "samsung galaxy note pro 12.2 lte black",
    "samsung galaxy note pro 12.2 p905 lte white",
    "samsung galaxy s duos 2 s7582",
    "samsung galaxy s4 pink twilight",
    "samsung galaxy s5 2g",
    "samsung galaxy s5 32gb",
    "samsung galaxy s5 air shuffle",
    "samsung galaxy s5 clone",
    "samsung galaxy s5 clone korea",
    "samsung galaxy s5 clone korea specs",
    "samsung galaxy s5 dual core",
    "samsung galaxy s5 dualcore",
    "samsung galaxy s5 korean clone specs"]`

```
 query for "samsung ga": returns multiple results
 query for "samsung gala": returns 0 results
 query for "samsung galax" return multiple results
```

Why is it that "samsung galax" and "samsung ga" has results but "samsung gala" does not. I have not implemented any kind of stopword control so that's not the problem. I'm certain something is off with my indexes.

Here is the pertinent index from the sphinx.conf file:

```
   index suggestions {

            source = suggestions

            path = /var/www/acme/maniac/sphinx/data/suggestions

            morphology = metaphone

            min_word_len = 3

            min_infix_len = 2
    }
```

I am doing this via the php client by the way. Here is the core method that performs the
sphinx search:

```
public function getKeywordSuggestions($queryString)
{
            $this->sphinxClient->SetMatchMode('SPH_MATCH_ANY');
            $this->sphinxClient->SetFieldWeights([
                    'keywords' => 50,
            ]);

            $this->sphinxClient->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
            $this->sphinxClient->AddQuery($queryString, 'suggestions');
            $suggestionLimit = 10;
            $this->sphinxClient->setLimits(0, $suggestionLimit, $suggestionLimit);

            $sphinxResult = $this->sphinxClient->RunQueries();
            /**
              * do some of my other mojo
              */
            return $result;
}
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

EDIT: sphinx version is 2.2.1

Comment: As far as the mysql problem is concerned, I can only help if I can see the structure of both the table and the actual query that is used against it.

Comment: What is the 'mysql problem' that you see? I can't see any question about mysql, this is purely a sphinx question.

Comment: Yeah. sphinx abstracts away the table indexing and full text searching. No direct db interaction is done.